# How to Detect File in Drag and Drop Method and Exclude Them From Being Copied in c#

Tags: c#

```
 DragDropEffects effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            var path = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
                effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;

            if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".png")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Files Are Not Allowed Please Choose a Folder !");
                return;
            }

            DashboardPathTextBox.Text = path;
            DragDropEffects dd = new DragDropEffects();
```

Now My Question is that if Someone Drag and Drop a File into Text Box it Shows a Message Text Box
as Above Code Works Fine for **.png** but i Want That this Work For all types of Files. Please Help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:
`if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".png")`
with:
`if (File.Exists(path))`

Comment: Thanks it is very helpfull